# JSLint warns that "document" is not fully defined on jQuery(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I get a

```
'document' has not been fully defined yet.
    $(document).ready(function () {
```

warning from `jsLint`.
I get why this happends but I would like my code to be warning free.

My question is - how do I either solve this in code (assign document to itself? `var document=document`?) or maybe make the warning go away some other way.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this a warning in the first place?  `document` has been defined.  Is this a bug in JSLint?

Comment: because, if I understand correctly, the use occurs within the definition of `document`. I.E - the variable is used inside its definition. similar to `var x = 3 + x;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can safely ignore that. If you don't want it to show anyway, rewrite it like so

```
$(function () {
    // Document is ready
});
```

`$(function () {})` and `$(document).ready(function () {})` are [equivalent](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 56):

You can simply use

```
/*jslint browser:true */
```

in the beginning of the code to assume a browser.

Answer (score 4):

Use the shorthand:

```
$(function() {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer to keep your code the way you have it, you can tell JSlint to be OK with your decision:

```
/*global document*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
}
```

This indicates that `document` has been defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

JSLint requires that you assume a browser in the selector options. the document will be defined then. Using $ will not help here...not in JSLint anyway.

Answer (score 0):

create an .jsintrc on root folder, with this:

`{ 
    "browser": true
}`

You can see all options in [JSHint Options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/)